# Create an external form to launch a search

Tags: integration

I wanted to include a custom form on our intranet that would initiate a contact search when submitted, like the quick search does if you enter text and press Enter.

I copied the form but when it came through to the search page a message popped up saying "Because your session timed out, we have reset the search page."

Answer (score 3):

The reason was that my form was missing `qfKey`. This is a [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) key generated as part of QuickForm forms.

This key must be generated for the particular form in use. By using XDebug in Vim, I was able to find out that the form name must be `CRM_Contact_Controller_Search`, and that it expects a sequence number too.

So my form is generated as follows:

```
<?php
// ...
civicrm_initialize();                                                                
$qfKey = htmlspecialchars(CRM_Core_Key::get('CRM_Contact_Controller_Search', 1));    
$mySearchForm = <<<HTML                                            
                                                                                     
<form action="/civicrm/contact/search/advanced" method="post">
  <div>
    <label>Search name or email                                                 
      <input type="text" name="sort_name" accesskey="q" />         
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_location" value="1" />                         
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_custom" value="1" />                           
    <input type="hidden" name="qfKey" value="$qfKey"/>                               
    <input type="hidden" name="_qf_Advanced_refresh" value="Search" />               
  </div>                                                                                                                
</form>          
HTML;
```

Posting here as it took me ages to figure out!